# Unknown event in MIDI file

Tags: python, binary, midi

As I've posted about before, I am writing a MIDI parser in Python. I am encountering an error where my parser is getting stuck because it's trying to read an event called `2a`, but such an event does not exist. below is an excerpt from the MIDI file in question:

```
5d7f 00b5 5d7f 00b6 5d7f 00b1 5d00 00b9
5d00 8356 9923 7f00 2a44 0192 367f 0091
237f 0099 4640 0092 2f7c 0099 3f53 0b3f
```

I have parsed the file by hand, and I am getting stuck in the same spot as my parser! The MIDI file plays, so I know it's valid, but I'm certain that I am reading the events wrong.

Comment: Please provide full MIDI file. There is no MIDI event with status byte `2a` so you're definitely reading data wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Standard MIDI Files 1.0 specification](https://www.midi.org/specifications-old/item/the-midi-1-0-specification) says:

> Running status is used: status bytes of MIDI channel messages may be omitted if the preceding event is a MIDI channel message with the same status. The first event in each MTrk chunk must specify status. Delta-time is *not* considered an event itself: it is an integral part of the syntax for an MTrk event. Notice that running status occurs *across* delta-times.

Your excerpt would be decoded as follows:

```
delta  <- event ------->
time   status parameters
-----  ------ ----------
          ... 5d 7f
00      b5    5d 7f
00      b6    5d 7f
00      b1    5d 00
00      b9    5d 00
83 56   99    23 7f
00            2a 44
01      92    36 7f
00      91    23 7f
00      99    46 40
00      92    2f 7c
00      99    3f 53
0b            3f ...
```